# Speed of two objects orbiting around a central axis

Tags: velocity, speed, angular-velocity

This question has been bugging me for quite some time and i'm not too sure if i'm missing out some important factor in the understanding of this scenario:

Given two objects of equal mass and size both orbiting around a central axis *x* where ObjectA is distance *n* away from *x* and ObjectB is distance *2n* away from *x*.

Now lets assume some force *f* is being applied to ObjectA and force *2f* being applied to ObjectB such that it takes the exact same time for ObjectA and ObjectB to do one full orbit around *x*.

Logically, there will have to be a greater force being applied to ObjectB to make it travel faster, as it has a greater circumference around *x*, in order for it to complete the orbit at the same time ObjectA completes its orbit.

However, if we were to join ObjectA to ObjectB via a long pipe for example and only apply a single force *f* on the pipe such that both objects will orbit around *x* at the same time.

How is it now that both objects will complete the orbit at the same time using one single force but yet ObjectB still has a larger circumference which means it has a greater distance to travel in order to complete the orbit?

P.S. Clearly i'm no physics expert and lack the knowledge for the proper terminology for the concepts I described above.

Answer (score 2):

> How is it now that both objects will complete the orbit at the same time using one single force but yet ObjectB still has a larger circumference which means it has a greater distance to travel in order to complete the orbit?

As you have connected the two identical objects **by a pipe (of course a rigid** **body)** and  applying a force on the pipe such that a point on the pipe- length is fixed and the pipe is rotating about an axis passing through the point .
As you have suggested the point fixed is off centre - one body is at distance n and another  at 2n from the fixed axis.

Though you are not fixing the point of  application of the force f being applied, say its acting on the body A.
The moment of the force **f x n**  will act and rotate it around the fixed axis
this torque will act and produce angular acceleration such that

**Torque = moment of inertia of the rigid body. Angular acceleration**

very much identical to force acting on a body producing linear acceleration.
now the speed generated will depend on **the torque** i.e. in turn on the moment of inertia which is kept constant.
now  the **time period** for one complete rotation will depend on where you applied f-i.e. **how far from the axis of rotation ; as it changes value of the torque.**

your question as to why  earlier you applied two forces without the pipe-connectivity f and 2f on the two bodies and their period of rotation was same and now you only apply f and both are moving with exactly same period but one point is missed that the pipe has converted the two bodies as part of a rigid body and internal forces are there to see that they are connected and move identically.
**As to the time period of rotation one has to check whether they change or not in two situations.**

In  the first case when your masses were circling  at distances n and 2n radii
They  must need two forces
**F(A) =(mass.n. angular velocity^2 )  and F(B) =(mass.2n.angular velocity^2 )**

as masses are same and angular velocity is same (as per your specification) you were taking the centripetal force towards the point x  as F(B) = 2.F(A)  or 2f and f, but they were essentially forces directed to the centre of motion.
If you apply  f only in the new situatiion towards the centre , along the pipe no roational motion will take place as the torque will be zero.

**As Torque is cross product of force and radius vector from the fixed  axis and both are collinear.**

Answer (score 0):

> However, if we were to join ObjectA to ObjectB via a long pipe for example and only apply a single force f on the pipe such that both objects will orbit around x at the same time.

Perhaps by this you mean that you can make this happen by applying only a single *additional* force.  Because you are accelerating the masses, they are necessarily applying forces to the rod.

Imagine that you simply set the rod spinning.  As it spins around it will reach a point where mass A is pulling the rod (and the other mass) to the left, while mass B is pulling the rod (and the other mass) to the right.

At this point you can apply an additional force $f$ to the rod.  If your force is applied to the left, you are decreasing the net force on mass A and increasing the net force on mass B.  You are applying one force, but that force is not equal to the net force on either object.